# Get Data in VBA that can be used by any user

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import a file from the desktop.  However, I need this to be used by different users.
Below is how it is written to work on "Mark's" desktop.  How do Imake it so it will work on any users desktop?

```
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\next.txt", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "next"
    .FieldNames = True
```

Same issue when saving the file at the end:

```
        Sheets("Loader").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Load_File" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".CSV", _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With
```

End Sub

Comment: `Environ("USERPROFILE")` will give `C:\Users\Mark` part.